# Dynamic field assignment based on generic string union

Tags: typescript, string, generics, union, mapped-types

So I want a function that'll add fields and functions to the object based on provided arguments.
The problem is that in the function it doesn't recognise types of these dynamic fields.
The simplest example showing the problem:

```
type Extended<Base extends object, Name extends string> =
  Base & Record<Name, string> & Record<`${Name}Something`, boolean>;

const addFields = <Base extends object, Name extends string>(
  obj: Base, names: ReadonlyArray<Name>
): Extended<Base, Name> => {
  return names.reduce((acc, name) => {
    acc[name] = "test"; // error!
    //~~~~~~~
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Extended<Base, Name>[Name]'.(2322)
    acc[`${name}Something`] = true; // error!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 
    // 'Extended<Base, Name>[`${Name}Something`]'.(2322)
    return acc;
  }, { ...obj } as Extended<Base, Name>)
}

const test = addFields({ x: 123 }, ["y"]);
test.x;
test.y;
test.y = "test2";
test.ySomething = false;
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AJhFAeAQgQwM7QQLIp5QD2ARgFYQDGwANFAHI4C2hxqZewATgEskAcwB8UALxRcBKADIoAJXrl+mNp2Z8hoiYpV01mAAYASAN6aIAXwDK5TsAAWwkScaVy5ADYQcSGIA3ACwAFDhRkh8UDgoKABighA+pFJQ2PhciDwUNPRMrBzZJLwCbmIAFFTUAFwyWcxIxXj1KnHkSD4gAIL8-DggGNZiAJT18DlomLIQzCNSEhbhUFD8EMAArvxIUM2ceAB06yibdBCVlTh0dE3Fo4tQy2Grq9d0ANr7EAC66QBEiD4-1CL1e7w+5gs33sjg2rlEJj+0gEmwgoNeaw22127wxUBszAshxJNRssTIkxI6EyBHmxTG4Rs4UinRiQOA6TiiWSqTwlQscHqAEYAEwAZkJUA+-xA-x+o1BHMOcCVED4hxAao1IABHNFIPCypADicCJE6QAZjgfAQgkA)

Is there a way to make typescript recognise these dynamic fields in the function properly or type it differently to avoid that problem while still maintaining type safety?

Comment: Since you're already asserting `{...obj} as Extended<Base, Name>` you're kind of playing loose with type safety... you might as well just assert everywhere you are having trouble.  But if you want to try to get the compiler to see what you're doing as safe, you could widen `acc` to the relevant member of the intersection before the assignment, as shown [in this TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOxa6N). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I mean it's kind of workaround that solves my problem in a weird way. It gives an idea of why it doesn't work the way I thought. The expected type for values is `boolean & string` as typescript treats `Name` and `${Name}Something` as fields that can overlap I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler isn't very good about verifying assignability to properties of [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of
[generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) types, unfortunately.  There have been some issues about this filed in GitHub, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#38796](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38796), but I haven't seen an authoritative comment about why exactly this happens.

Note that one complicating factor is that it's actually sometimes quite difficult to work out such types, even for a human being.  Your type

```
type Extended<Base extends object, Name extends string> =
  Base & Record<Name, string> & Record<`${Name}Something`, boolean>;
```

does strange things if `Name` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) where one of the members is equal to another member with `"Something"` appended to it.  Like:

```
type Hmm = Extended<{}, "a" | "aSomething">;
// type Hmm = never
```

since you get `{} & {a: string, aSomething: string} & {aSomething: boolean, aSomethingSomething: boolean}`, so the `aSomething` property would need to be the impossible `string & boolean` intersection, and the whole object reduces to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Thus it might be technically correct for the compiler to complain about `acc[name] = "test"`, if `name` is `"aSomething"`, then `"test"` fails to be `string & boolean`.

I think these issues could probably be handled by the TS team if they ever tackled such things.  For now, we should just approach it as a missing feature and work around it.

---

My preferred workaround in cases like this is to *widen* the intersection type to one of its members (if `x` is of type `A & B` then it should be safe to widen `x` to either `A` or `B`) before doing the property access.  For the code in this question, that looks like:

```
const addFields = <Base extends object, Name extends string>(
  obj: Base, names: ReadonlyArray<Name>
): Extended<Base, Name> => {
  return names.reduce((acc, name) => {
    const acc1: Record<Name, string> = acc; // okay
    acc1[name] = "test"; // okay
    const acc2: Record<`${Name}Something`, boolean> = acc; // okay
    acc2[`${name}Something`] = true; // okay
    return acc;
  }, { ...obj } as Extended<Base, Name>)
}
```

First I widen the type of `acc` to `Record<Name, string>` in the `acc1` variable, which then allows the writing of a `string` value to its `name` property.  Then I widen the type of `acc` to `` Record<`${Name}Something`, boolean> `` in the `acc2` variable, which then allows the writing of a `boolean` value to its `` `${name}Something` `` property.

This all type checks, because instead of trying to evaluate `(Record<K1, V1> & Record<K2, V2>)[K1]`, the compiler can evaluate the more straightforward `Record<K1, V1>[K1]` to get `V1`.

Again, it's possibly unsound when `name` itself ends with `"Something"`, but I'm not too worried about that edge case here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AJhFAeAQgQwM7QQLIp5QD2ARgFYQDGwANFAHI4C2hxqZewATgEskAcwB8UALwBYAFBQouAlABkUAEr1y-TG07M+Q0RLWa62zAAMAJAG89EAL4Blcp2AALYSMvNK5cgAbCBwkMQBuOTlQSCgACXZ2KVhuNExbR2YAIhwsqAAfKBzXdy9RLIi5AHoqqBjoBKTJKCQIADcIfijZcyQ+KBwUFAAxQQhA0mTsfC5EHgoaeiZWDlmSXgFvMQAKOQUqagAuRRnmJFW8Y81B8iRAkABBfn4cEAwHMTkASmP4ObTpgRmB8pBJbHsoPwIMAAK78JAtC4AOihKBhdAg222ODodDOqy+oKg4PkCigvX6OLoAEYrlodO9VgZNsZklTwlAahQANavCEKKnUgDa504AF1kllEHwshyueReSB+eTbpTcQAmOnmBk2eyrFxuaFlHx+ALBUISZrszm1BV80kCjVC3WipwlI3eSwS5oCGEQOW2xXKqGw+EDXGRUmZYlQJFxg5QRwDMh-EjoQEQYGrMRfOSOboU4B1CD9K1DUbjUjbWxQODHanqgDMieYQqyICyYq+kelwCRcB7Jb7IEHfCRIElvfVsuiQ-H7s83mSADMcIECJG5EA)