# How to handle a reduce on union type

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code: ([TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sDdpAIcLYZLEaqZajFbTu1N8dyAHpOzAogMyqywBkeqUypQsKRUIc8AAaNTiGB-GDEew8Xhm+nERwSmAl2CKZT4RfcPKOOEZWpRXde2CcKAQPCm7swKAADykuyqAEYAKy7OcXL+VQAMwAAwnCOFxgVUJx9lgFxvHgGQlj0MC-qe6iAv+FxaCAfJQHaaE-su3CjmBGHnhBpEXNQAywChJ7kdQZ5YaaYq4pK5Q6mAFKKk6NKQsKorYhxVqDrxjrUtmJDCuxEpWuOk6HBJmbKi6xBCdwcl4qUikMspGZUlmKoacA2jAPo0AwJSSrOgA0lAQ5CBccwLEsSEhjClFas2MZBtWWpNn6flVrsYSWYYAAKuAAMJesQgy0nAL6vpEpEZDZ-HeA5Q7OJkprEJQvD+e82yFGILBSJwa5zgeKhjK02BzqUkI5VVDh8HOUSoK87VrtoIQwGZMAAGT5cUgR2ceMBJHxUlkIEcDBIEoHLZc4i7MEwQNW0ejTMAb79IMG69CAvYDNQpDRVAcUJSA2zObQU1vmlpQZXNxl4DleD8AAFKaLUFDNmXzXgk3BMAACUqzXbdiU5nZziCEUuRLMSWAnoDxAAHRLLp8T-Z0OS-XEsQw7F8Xw9YiPNb4UizZJn3gytwSQ0IyN5kTz7cgREDXvg+5KCoyG1Cl3REvz1DnfBdmRQkj5EyUpOBIDNDYxVUDBM5qvUNjdVQGEivFKT2OFcVValZC2OwngXq-SjRslNjzs6zOnOO1jbVlL46viG7judN1vUXHUWJYHgACCpEADLEFoyB4AAQmA2w5SrPsa8E2NB8gM5tgHMDaJDwqK2j44nqTJdTP7RPCGbJWlGVMAhNoy4ZHAsOU-dCP8KaxdmbIQA))

```
type TDeliveriesStatsDatum<TName = string> = {name: TName; value: number};
type TDeliveriesStatsData<TName = string> = TDeliveriesStatsDatum<TName>[];

interface IDeliveriesStats {
    meta: {
        delivery_count: number;
        transport_count: number;
    };
    progress: TDeliveriesStatsData<"done" | "not_done" | "cancelled">;
    disputes: TDeliveriesStatsData<"disputed" | "undisputed">;
    loading_punctuality: TDeliveriesStatsData<"ontime" | "delayed" | "unknown">;
    unloading_punctuality: TDeliveriesStatsData<"ontime" | "delayed" | "unknown">;
    cmr_document: TDeliveriesStatsData<"done_with_cmr_document" | "done_without_cmr_document">;
    non_cmr_document: TDeliveriesStatsData<
        "done_with_non_cmr_document" | "done_without_non_cmr_document"
    >;
    // for delays and durations, name is a string containing the values in minutes of the steps
    // ex: "_15",  "15_30" and "30_" for "less than 15 minutes", "between 15 and 30 minutes" and "more than 30 minutes"
    loading_delay: TDeliveriesStatsData;
    unloading_delay: TDeliveriesStatsData;
    loading_duration: TDeliveriesStatsData;
    unloading_duration: TDeliveriesStatsData;
}

type DeliveriesStatsKeys = "progress" | "disputes" | "cmr_document" | "non_cmr_document";


type TPieChartData<T extends DeliveriesStatsKeys> = {
    augmentedData: {name: string, value: number, dataKey: string, fill: string}[] 
} & {
    [K in IDeliveriesStats[T][0]["name"]]: number;
};

export const formatPieChartData = <K extends DeliveriesStatsKeys>(
    data: IDeliveriesStats[K]
): TPieChartData<K> => {
    return data.reduce(
        (acc: TPieChartData<K>, datum: IDeliveriesStats[K][0]) => {
            // keep these values to extract them for KPIs
            acc[datum.name] = datum.value;

            acc.augmentedData.push({
                ...datum,
                dataKey: datum.name,
                fill: "colorsAndLabelsByDataKey[datum.name].fill," // written this way to avoid adding too much unrelated code
            });
            return acc;
        },
        {augmentedData: []} as TPieChartData<K>
    );
};
```

The compiler error is the following:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ (callbackfn: (previousValue: TDeliveriesStatsDatum<"done" | "not_done" | "cancelled">, 
currentValue: TDeliveriesStatsDatum<"done" | "not_done" | "cancelled">, 
currentIndex: number, array: TDeliveriesStatsDatum<...>[]) => TDeliveriesStatsDatum<...>): TDeliveriesStatsDatum<...>;
 (callbackfn: (previousValue: TDeliver...' 
has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

How can I type `IDeliveriesStats` or `TPieChartData` to get Typescript to understand that `acc[datum.name]` is correctly typed?

Comment: This is another effect of TS's lack of direct support for *correlated unions* as mentioned in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the recommended fix is a certain refactoring described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  There's a little more to it than that, but the final code for the example here looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQYeJw). If that fully addresses your issue I can write up a full answer about it. Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, that seems like a good solution. I'm not sure I understand exactly how you came to it though ;)

Also I think redefining _acc to cast seems a bit weird? I would write it this way: `(acc as Record<DeliveriesStatsName[K], number>)[datum.name] = datum.value;`

Comment: Type assertions via `x as T` allow both widenings (which are generally safe) and narrowings (which are generally unsafe).  Type annotations on variables (via `const _x: T = x`) only allow widenings.  So if you're doing something safe and want the compiler to verify it, annotations are preferable to assertions.  If you are just looking for ease of use then a type assertion is fine, but then you're not really getting TypeScript to "understand that `acc[datum.name]` is correctly typed" as asked.  I'll explain more when I write up the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why we need to widen the type in the first place; why doesn't TS understand assigning `datum.name` to `acc` directly? (It fails with `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'PieChartData<K>[DeliveriesStatsName[K]]'.`)

Comment: I don't know of an authoritative source for why it fails; in general, the compiler gets confused when indexing into `Record<K, V> & Foo` with a key of (generic) type `K`.  Widening is essentially a way to work around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue here is that the compiler can't follow the correlation between the type of `acc` and the type of `datum.name` unless these types are expressed in a particular way, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Otherwise the correlation is lost, and the type checking reverts to treating `acc` and `datum.name` as unrelated types constrained to [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and it complains about the possibility that the source property and the target property correspond to different keys (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769)).  Of course there *is* no such possibility (or it's unlikely, anyway), but the compiler can't see it.

Another issue is that the compiler sees the `data.reduce()` call as trying to call a union of generic methods.  That's because `data` is of a generic type that can only be seen as an array if it is evaluated eagerly, and that widens `K` to its constraint.  Calling unions of generic methods is not really supported; see [microsoft/TypeScript#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373). Again, the type of `data` needs to be expressed in a particular way so that the compiler knows at the outset that this is a single array type with a single generic `reduce()` method.

---

The required refactoring would be to write everything in terms of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) key type with which you [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)... usually as a function of a basic "mapping" type.  Here's how you might do it:

```
// basic mapping type
interface DeliveriesStatsName {
    progress: "done" | "not_done" | "cancelled"
    disputes: "disputed" | "undisputed"
    cmr_document: "done_with_cmr_document" | "done_without_cmr_document"
    non_cmr_document: "done_with_non_cmr_document" | "done_without_non_cmr_document"
}

type DeliveriesStats<K extends keyof DeliveriesStatsName> =
    DeliveriesStatsData<DeliveriesStatsName[K]>;

interface AugmentedData {
    augmentedData: {
        name: string, value: number, dataKey: string, fill: string;
    }[]
}

type BasePieChartData<K extends keyof DeliveriesStatsName> =
    Record<DeliveriesStatsName[K], number>;

type PieChartData<K extends keyof DeliveriesStatsName> =
    BasePieChartData<K> & AugmentedData;
```

In the above, `DeliveriesStats<K>` acts like your `IDeliveriesStats[K]`, but it's represented explicitly in terms of the mapping type `DeliveriesStatsName`.  Analogously, `PieChartData<K>` acts like your `TPieChartData<K>` except for the explicit mapping type representation.

The goal is that the compiler should see that `data` is of a single array type, and that `acc[datum.name] = datum.value` is indexing into `Record<XXX, number>` with a key of type `XXX` and therefore accepts a `number`.

We nearly achieve these goals, but not quite:

```
export const formatPieChartData = <K extends keyof DeliveriesStatsName>(
    data: DeliveriesStats<K>
): PieChartData<K> => {
    return data.reduce((acc, datum) => {

        acc[datum.name] = datum.value; // error!
        // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'PieChartData<K>[DeliveriesStatsName[K]]'.

        acc.augmentedData.push({
            ...datum,
            dataKey: datum.name,
            fill: "colorsAndLabelsByDataKey[datum.name].fill,"
        });
        return acc;
    }, { augmentedData: [] } as AugmentedData as PieChartData<K>);
    // double assertion needed here to get the compiler to see the types as related

};
```

The goal of `data.reduce()` being callable has been met, which is good.  But `acc[datum.name] = datum.value` is still causing an error.  And that's because of an issue with intersections of generic record types.  I don't know of an authoritative issue about this (the closest I can find is [ms/TS#38796](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38796)), but if you have a type like `Record<K, V> & Foo` where `K` is generic, and try to index into it with a key `K`, the compiler loses the thread.  The workaround here is to safely widen `Record<K, V> & Foo` to just `Record<K, V>` and then index into that.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74606391/2887218) for more information.

So let's do that:

```
export const formatPieChartData = <K extends keyof DeliveriesStatsName>(
    data: DeliveriesStats<K>
): PieChartData<K> => {
    return data.reduce((acc, datum) => {

        const _acc: BasePieChartData<K> = acc; // okay
        _acc[datum.name] = datum.value; // okay

        acc.augmentedData.push({
            ...datum,
            dataKey: datum.name,
            fill: "colorsAndLabelsByDataKey[datum.name].fill,"
        });
        return acc;
    }, { augmentedData: [] } as AugmentedData as PieChartData<K>);

};
```

The widening from `acc` to `_acc` is verified by the compiler as safe, and then the assignment to `_acc[datum.name]` works as intended!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-htvitAKAAlLwz5jjuBj0PqkSJMApBoGwUBgfgAB0iRpKQ3hAUBXieM6VhwYwaGogakSUTYYEUARRoQHY76seQBHCKIECCAA9EJhJoLEaAAIQcm8Il8OiUAAOTdr2ilQB07xXnGWCIHEHCSI0UDADERkKYpSGvnou42JB3LClwop2HYikEQxjHXpkd4lJRvDromKYvuOVkGFAlHCaJMQUvgIAyZE3meJ4LFWOxIRcUwPF8baglQHJkXRW5jGUQRmrKseaS8gRXRYLsQHoe5kQEY1PGWrFjH4e6IC8BlHEtfVbx+gGBT1vADZYPKYwADL4NI8BYNGIC8h1SVYbxHF2ARA3wJarzubIcEhu5mHYbhYUcrI1qsCV2rla6vD2HIoXkoqpUuCeBCPUOAXIROu77ai8hAA)

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer! Feels a bit like fighting the compiler but I guess the correct way to handle this would be a deeper refactoring of the code I'm dealing with anyway.